# Speeding a video by 5x and triming it

Tags: video

I want to

A: trim a section out of a video (the jitter when I pressed record) and delete the trimmed section.

and

B: speed the remaining part of it up by 5x

Any help would be appreciated. I can add more details if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I can really recommend [mikeycalmeyers videos on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/c/mikeycalmeyers/playlists). He has a whole series exlaining how to do video editing with Blender.

To answer your question, there are [multiple ways to trim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw-GPKEMNxY&index=5&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4):

Option 1) Select your video and audio by holding `shift` and `right clicking` on them. Then put the green marker at the moment in time where you want to make a cut. From the menu just below your video sequence editor (the one with the tracks) choose `Strip > Cut (soft) at frame`, or press the shortcut key `K`. This will split it into separate parts, so you can delete the parts you want to remove.

Option 2) Select the arrows on the left side of both your video and audio tracks by holding down `shift` and `right clicking` them. Then you can move them by pressing `G` and `moving your mouse`. For precise control use your `arrow keys`. When you moved it to the right location press `enter`.

To [speed up your video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrX1sK_ZQqs&index=27&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4):
Select (only) your video track with a `right click`. Then go to the menu in the video sequence editor and choose `Add > Effect strip > Speed Control`. Then on the right side uncheck `Stretch to input strip length`, set `speed factor` to `1` and `multiply speed` to `5` (or any other speed you like). You will need to drag the arrow on the right side of your original video track (so not the speed control) to match the new duration of your video track. Changing the speed of audio does not work this way, so I would use Audacity to change the speed and then import it into Blender.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "hard cut" Shift K to trim both ends of the strip. Then use a speed effect and drag the end of the strip to the desired length. If you don't use a hard cut then the last frame may not be the one you want.